# Cannot read property 'removePerson' of undefined in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to delete a `Person` object from my table on the server using `PersonId` and a `url`. First I show the list of `Person` objects and next to each object I have a `delete-button` to delete the object. I am trying to pass the value of `PersonId` to the method `removePerson(person)`. I am using this method as test to show the `PersonId`to the console, but I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removePerson' of undefined`. This is my code:

```
return (
            <table id="myTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Person id</th>
                    <th>Person name</th>
                    <th>Person Surname</th>
                    <th>Action </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.persons.map(function(person , i) {
                    return(
                        <tr key={i}>
                            <td>{person.PersontId}</td>
                            <td>{person.Name}</Link></td>
                            <td>{person.Surname}</td>
                            <td> <button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onClick={()=>this.removePerson({person})}
                                >Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The method I use as a test is:

```
removePerson(person) {
    console.log(person.PersonId); //Just a test to catch PersonId
}
```

But if I change `onClick={()=>this.removePerson({person})}` with `onClick={()=>console.log({project})}` I get the `Person` object to the console each time I click on `Delete`-button. 
Why I am getting this error and why I cannot pass the `person` object to `removePerson(person)`? - Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to `bind` the `map callback function`, use `arrow function`: `{this.props.persons.map((person , i) => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use es6 arrow function `()=>` instead of `function` . `this` inside callback function refer to the callback method.

```
  {this.props.persons.map((person , i)=> {
                return(
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td>{person.PersontId}</td>
                        <td>{person.Name}</Link></td>
                        <td>{person.Surname}</td>
                        <td> <button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onClick={()=>this.removePerson({person})}
                            >Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
```

Comment: `@Ved` I changed to es6 arrow function, but when I click the `delete`-button I am getting `undefined` in the console. Is `removePerson`-method incorrectly written?

Comment: @carl your passing an object, `this.removePerson({person})` is like writing `this.removePerson({person: person})`, I'd replace it with ``this.removePerson(person)`

Comment: Thanks `@Ved`. I see my fails now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem with your code,

1. As @ved pointed out, You need to bind your map function to be able to use the `this.removePerson()` method
2. You are destructuring the person object and passing as argument to function. You don't need to do that. Change `onClick={() => this.removePerson({person})}` to `onClick={() => this.removePerson(person)}`

See the code below

```
 {this.props.persons.map((person , i)=> {
            return(
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{person.PersontId}</td>
                    <td>{person.Name}</Link></td>
                    <td>{person.Surname}</td>
                    <td> <button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onClick={()=>this.removePerson(person)}
                        >Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            );
        })}
```

Comment: `@Shubham Khatri` Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Glad to have helped